# USAMTS 2017-18 Round 2 Problems

Tags: discussion, contests

---

The USA Mathematical Talent Search (USAMTS) is a free mathematics competition open to all United States middle and high school students.

As opposed to most mathematics competitions, the USAMTS allows students a full month, or more, to work out their solutions. Carefully written justifications are required for each problem.

Students may use any materials - books, calculators, computers - but all the work must be their own. The USAMTS is run on the honor system - it is an individual competition, whose competitive role is very secondary. **While we want students to be able to use all resources available to them, we do not want students to be able to post questions and get answers on this forum.**

---

Two problems from round 1 were posted during the contest:

- [Are there two polygons that can be joined in different ways to form a triangle, a convex quadrilateral, and a convex pentagon?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2472695/are-there-two-polygons-that-can-be-joined-in-different-ways-to-form-a-triangle)
- [Set Theory Subset Question: Please Check my Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2484204/set-theory-subset-question-please-check-my-answer)

Round 2 is active now, and is due **November 27th.** If you all can please be careful to sheriff these problems being posted, I would really appreciate it!

Here are the round 2 problems for reference:

- http://usamts.org/Tests/Problems_29_2.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the notification, I will try to be vigilant.

Comment: Q5 was posted at least a couple other times (links to deleted questions): [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2456361/set-of-non-integer-rationals-such-that-every-integer-can-be-written-uniquely-as) [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2454937/infinite-set-of-rational-numbers)